# Iterating over numpy arrays to compare columns of different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to programming and had a question. If I had two numpy arrays:

```
A = np.array([[1,0,3], [2,6,5], [3,4,1],[4,3,2],[5,7,9]], dtype=np.int64)  
B = np.array([[3,4,5],[6,7,9],[1,0,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=np.int64)
```

I want to compare the last two columns of array A to the last two columns of array B, and then if they are equal, output the entire row to a new array. So, the output of these two arrays would be:

```
[1,0,3
1,0,3
5,7,9
6,7,9]
```

Because even though the first element does not match for the last two rows, the last two elements do.

Here is my code so far, but it is not even close to working. Can anyone give me some tips?

```
column_two_A = A[:,1]
column_two_B = B[:,1]

column_three_A = A[:,2]
column_three_B = B[:,2]

column_four_A = A[:,3]
column_four_B = B[:,3]

times = A[:,0]

for elementA in column_three_A: 
    for elementB in column_three_B: 
        if elementA == elementB: 
            continue 
        for elementC in column_two_A: 
            for elementD in column_two_B: 
                if elementC == elementD: 
                    continue
                for elementE in column_four_A: 
                    for elementF in column_four_B: 
                        if elementE == elementF:
                            continue 
                        element.append(time)
 print(element)
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear do you mean that you want to compare each row from A with each row from B and return both when the last two elements of both rows are identical ? Also your code is unintelligible please try to format it properly so that we can at least read it.

Comment: So to be clear, you want the rows of both arrays appended to the new array? Are the arrays of equal length or varying length like in your example?

Comment: Yes, I want both rows to be appended. The arrays are not of equal length which is something I was struggling with...help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, the give arrays are always going to be nx3. So there will always be three columns, I just don't know how many rows there will necessarily be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy holds many functions for that kind of tasks. Here is a solution to check if the values of A are in B. Add `print()` statements and check what `chk`, `chk2` and `x` are.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,0,3], [2,6,5], [3,4,1],[4,3,2],[5,7,9]], dtype=np.int64)
B = np.array([[3,4,5],[6,7,9],[1,0,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=np.int64)

c = []

for k in A:

    chk = np.equal(k[-2:], B[:, -2:])
    chk2 = np.all(chk, axis=1)
    x = (B[chk2, :])
    if x.size:
        c.append(x)

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out by staying up all night... thank you!

```
 `for i in range(len(A)):
     for j in range(len(B)):
         if A[i][1] == B[j][1]:
           if A[i][2] == B[j][2]:
               print(B[j])
               print(A[i])`
```